# Is the Image of a projective module still a projective module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Precisely, let $P$ be a projective module and $\partial:P\to Q$ be a module homomorphism. Then how do we prove that $Im\partial$ is still a projective module?

Comment: This isn't true. Every module is the image of a free module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false. Every module is the image of a free (hence projective) module. Yet, non-projective modules exist.

Comment: A very nice answer.